# How do I locate and remove Proprietary Drivers

Tags: package-management

I'm planning to move my ubuntu install to another machine. I think the proprietary drivers like those for nvidia and wireless might cause issues with that hardware. How can I find all these tricky packages and remove them before I make an image of my hard drive and proceed further.

I know I have a nvidia graphics card, I'll remove the drivers for that but I don't know what other problematic packages may be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of Ubuntu are you running:

1. In 12.04 and below search for the application called ["Additional
   Drivers"](http://img.hexus.net/v2/articles/linux-ati-nvidia/jockey-gtk-001.png)
2. In 12.10 it is a tab in ["Software Sources"](http://techhamlet.com/2012/10/additional-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10/).

From there you can remove the drivers you don't need. After a reboot, all open source drivers will be restored and "problematic packages" will be removed.